# Hotkey/shortcut to reduce the height of a multiline caret / block mode selection in IntelliJ [/PyCharm /other JetBrains IDE's]

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

As shown in the screenshot I have over-extended the block selection above the list of columns. I don't know any way to fix that besides starting the selection process over from the top.

[image]

So is that the only thing I can do? Or is there an analog to *extending* the lines selected by up-arrow to *diminishing* the lines selected ? If so what is the key combinations for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign shortcuts to **Clone Caret Above** / **Below** actions in the IDE Keymap settings:

[image: clone caret]

Comment: `Dr JetBrains` checks in. Thx for the tip.